# React component wont re-render after onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component called CamperList which renders an array of table row components. Two of the table head tags have onClick events which are supposed to toggle this.state.toggle and update the table. When I click the All Time Points tag the table updates but when I click the Points in past 30 days tag it won't update. Here is the code:

```
var CamperList = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   recent: [],
   toggle: true
  };
 },
 componentDidMount: function() {
  $.get('http://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent', function(data) {
      this.setState({
       recent: data
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },
 recent: function() {
  this.setState({toggle: true});
 },
 alltime: function() {
  this.setState({toggle: false});
 },
 render: function() {
  var camperNodes;
  if (this.state.toggle) {
   camperNodes = this.state.recent.map(function(camper, index) {
      return (
        <Camper index={index + 1} username={camper.username} recent={camper.recent} alltime={camper.alltime} />
      );
    });
  } else {
   var alltime = this.state.recent;
   alltime = alltime.sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.alltime - a.alltime;
       })
   camperNodes = alltime.map(function(camper, index) {
      return (
        <Camper index={index + 1} username={camper.username} recent={camper.recent} alltime={camper.alltime} />
      );
    });
  }
    return (
     <table className="table">
      <thead className="blue">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Camper Name</th>
        <th onClick={this.recent}>Points in past 30 days</th>
        <th onClick={this.alltime}>All time points</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
     {camperNodes}
    </tbody>
   </table>
    );
  }
});
```

Link to pen: http://codepen.io/ZacharyKearns/pen/dMvGNG/

Comment: What do you expect to happen? I'm pretty sure the click event handler works just fine, but your render logic is incorrect (somehow). Unfortunately we can't really help you if you don't tell us what you are trying to achieve. I *assume* you want the data to be sorted differently, but you haven't explained how. So far, you are always only sorting the data by `alltime`.

Comment: Sorry, When `this.recent` fires and sets `toggle` to `true` I want the component to re render with the list sorted by recent points.

Comment: But you are never sorting by recent points.

Answer (score 0):

Your `render` function has too much business logic in it, which makes your code difficult to reason about. Move that logic into the `recent` and `alltime` functions, such that they re-sort the camper array according to the objects' `alltime` or `recent` properties. For example:

```
alltime: function() {
   var sortedArr = [];
   //sort the array from highest alltime to lowest
   this.setState({
       recent: sortedArr
   })
}
```

That will automatically invoke the render function (which should just be rendering UI elements and not have any logic in it).